# Multiple commands in ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I'm currently running [Terracognita](https://github.com/cycloidio/terracognita/tree/master) through ECS - it deploys a container running Terracognita, scans through my running infrastructure and saves this to a file named New.tfstate. I then need to push this to an S3 bucket.

The Task Definition looks like this:

```
            ],
            "essential": true,
            "entryPoint": [
                "/app/terracognita"
            ],
            "command": [
                "aws,--tfstate,New.tfstate,--aws-default-region,eu-west-1",
                "aws,s3,cp,/app/terracognita/New.tfstate,s3://terracognitafiles"
            ],
            "environment": [],
            "mountPoints": [],
            "volumesFrom": [],
```

And the Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# build stage
FROM golang:1.17-alpine3.14 as builder

RUN apk add --update git

WORKDIR /app

COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .

RUN go mod download

COPY . .

RUN GIT_TAG=$(git describe --tags --always) && \
  CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -ldflags "-X github.com/cycloidio/terracognita/cmd.Version=$GIT_TAG"

# final stage
FROM alpine:3.14
COPY --from=builder /app/terracognita /app/
# https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10779
RUN apk --update add ca-certificates
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/terracognita"]
```

I've tried to seperate the commands - the first one works and tells me that everything has been written to New.tfstate and Terracognita has ran succesfully.

`aws,--tfstate,New.tfstate,--aws-default-region,eu-west-1`

But the second one doesn't.

`aws,s3,cp,/app/terracognita/New.tfstate,s3://terracognitafiles`

I've tried seperating these with &&, tried seperating them with quotes, etc. But there's no indication the second command is even running.
Here's how it looks in the actual task definition, where everything has to be seperated with commas:

`"aws,--tfstate,New.tfstate,--aws-default-region,eu-west-1","aws,s3,cp,/app/terracognita/New.tfstate,s3://terracognitafiles"`

Thank you for any assistance with this